# How can I redirect port 80 to a different port with Apache?

Tags: apache, redirects, tomcat

I have tomcat running on port 8080 and want a particular URL, lets say `http://example.com/app`, to actually point to `example.com:8080/app`

I have other content on the website that should remain unchanged.

Comment: Depends upon what you mean by 'point'.  Do you want to just redirect traffic from http://example.com/app to http://example.com:8080/app (and thus exposing port 8080 to external traffic) or do you want to hide the existance of Tomcat behind Apache, by running all requests through Apache to Tomcat, and returning all results back from Tomcat through Apache to the user?

Comment: hide Tomcat; users should not see 8080

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is not a redirect but actually a proxy. Check out the information found in the [mod_proxy config page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). You should end up with something like:

```
ProxyPass /app http://example.com:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse /app http://example.com:8080/app
```

Comment: Specifically, a `Reverse Proxy`